# Trouble Passing an Array to an Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Ok, so I have an assignment where we must create a java program which asks the user a contacts' name and and a variable amount of the numbers and number types(work, voip..) associated with the contact.  The toString() method is suppose to print the contacts name and associated numbers and number types.

Am I passing my Array correctly from my main method to the phoneBookEntry constructor correctly? ( I know there are compile errors, etc, but I want to make sure I am passing the Arrays correctly. Also, is my approach correct?

Suppose to follow UML table accordingly here:

Phone book entry

---

- name : String
- phoneNumbers : String[]
- phoneTypes : String[]

  ---
- PhoneBookEntry()
- PhoneBookEntry(nam : String) :
- PhoneBookEntry(nam : String, numbers : String[], types : String[]) :
- getName() : String
- setName(nam : String) : void
- getPhoneNumber(type : String) : String
- setNumbers(numbers : String[], types : String[]) : void
- toString() : String

  ---

Thanks!

Here is what I have so far:

```
package phonebookentry;


import java.awt.List;
import java.util.*;

public class PhoneBookEntry
{
  private String name;
  private String[] phoneNumbers,phoneTypes;

  /**
   * @param args
   */
  public PhoneBookEntry()
  {


  }


  public PhoneBookEntry(String nam, String[]numbers, String[]types)
  {
    phoneNumbers = numbers;
    name = nam;
    phoneTypes = types;
    toString();
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name; 
  }
  public void setName(String nam)
  {

  }
  public String[]  getPhoneNumber(String type)
  {
    return phoneTypes;
  }
  public void setNumbers(String[] numbers, String[] types)
  {
    this.phoneNumbers = numbers;
    this.phoneTypes = types;
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    for (int index = 0; index < phoneNumbers.length; index ++ )
      return System.out.println(nam, this.phoneNumbers, this.phoneTypes) ;

  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String phoneN = "0";

    ArrayList<String> Ptypes = new ArrayList<String>();


    ArrayList<String> Pnumbers = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (!phoneN.equals("-1"))
    {


      String phoneT;
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      // Create an ArrayList to hold some names.

      System.out.println("Phone number of Contact: (Input -1, to end)");
      phoneN = input.nextLine();
      if (phoneN.equals("-1"))
        break;  
      Pnumbers.add(phoneN);
      System.out.print("Type of phone number(mobile,home,VOIP,work,etc..):");
      phoneT = input.nextLine();
      Ptypes.add(phoneT);
    } 

    String nam = "fas";
    String[] types = Ptypes.toArray(new String[Ptypes.size()]);
    String[] numbers = Pnumbers.toArray(new String[Pnumbers.size()]);
    PhoneBookEntry passPhone = new PhoneBookEntry(nam,numbers,types);

    passPhone.setNumbers(numbers,
        types);

  }

}
```

Comment: is my main method correct? am i passing the Arraylist correctly to the PhoneBookEntry() Constructor?

Comment: Try posting to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: That did not mean anything, but I do not see any errors.
Try to compile it :)

Comment: your code does not compile, toString returns void

Comment: Feel free to edit your question with your actual question rather than posting it as a comment. Also, does your code compile? What happens when you run it? If you get compiler errors, you should post them. Finally, is there a reason that `PhoneBookEntry` uses arrays rather than using a `List` directly? This would make sending the `ArrayList`s much easier since you wouldn't have to convert them to arrays.

Comment: Your way to convert `ArrayList<String>` to a `String`-array is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toString() method should concatenate out all the phone numbers(I presume)

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder phoneBook = new StringBuilder();  
        //Generate comma separated entries of phone book  
        for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumbers.length && i < phoneTypes.length; i++ ) {
            if (i > 0) { 
                phoneBook.append(','); 
            }
            phoneBook = phoneBook.append(phoneNumbers[i])
                                 .append(':')
                                 .append(phoneTypes[i])

        }

        return phoneBook.toString();  
    }
```

Other comments

- There is no point calling the toString() method in the constructor.
- You should also check whether the lentgh of phoneTypes and phoneNumbers are equal in the constructor.
- An empty constructor should be an empty phoneBook. By default the private fields are null. So the toString() method might blow up.
- Separate get/set methods for phone numbers/types along with constructors are a bad choice. Instead keep a List where phone numbers could be added/deleted/updated. I guess that is the next assignment. Good Luck !

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful for console output!

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int index = 0; index < phoneNumbers.length; index ++ )
  return System.out.println(index) ;
```

That returns nothing . `println()` returns `void` . Again , you are returning at the first iteration of the loop . You should construct a `String` and return it after the loop. Your `public String toString()` should return a `String` to avoid the compilation error.
Something like this :

```
public String toString()
{
  StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
  for (int index = 0; index < phoneNumbers.length; index ++ )
    str.append(...) ; // append whatever you want to display
  return str.toString();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this result in a compiler error?

Comment: It should , i guess why it doesn't or the OP !!!

Comment: My point is that your "answer" should probably be a comment to the effect that the code doesn't compile rather than stating "This returns nothing." Since it doesn't compile, talking about the semantics of the `return` statement is less the helpful.